# Where is the new element added in a java queue

Tags: java, list, queue

I am using [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) to create a queue. Everything is working fine but I get a bit confused. Is the new value added in the end of the list? This is the result of the for loop

```
public static CircularFifoQueue<Client> usersDelay = new CircularFifoQueue<Client>(4);

System.out.println(newValue);
   list.add(newValue);
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(i+ ": "+list.get(i));
    }

New value : 345
0: 345
--------------------------
New value : 369
0: 345
1: 369
--------------------------
New value : 444
0: 345
1: 369
2: 444
--------------------------
New value : 432
0: 345
1: 369
2: 444
3: 432
--------------------------
New value : 633
0: 369
1: 444
2: 432
3: 633
--------------------------
New value : 346
0: 444
1: 432
2: 633
3: 346
--------------------------
New value : 299
0: 432
1: 633
2: 346
3: 299
--------------------------
New value : 423
0: 633
1: 346
2: 299
3: 423
--------------------------
New value : 538
0: 346
1: 299
2: 423
3: 538
--------------------------
```

If I want to get the last 10 recently added element, shall I loop the list from the end to the beginning?

Comment: what is the type of `list`?

Comment: Link updated. List contain custom object of class Client.

Comment: Run the loop as `for(int i=Math.max(0,list.size()-10-1),i<list.size();i++)` to print last `10` elements of the list.

Comment: Try to post the full code. It seems that you have declared queue with the size `4` and as per documentation of the `add` function, If your queue is full then It will remove least recently added element to add the new one. Same thing is happening here so check it or post it.

Comment: *If I want to get the last 10 recently added element, shall I loop the list from the end to the beginning?* Assuming the documentation doesn't explain it, why don't you just try doing both, and see by yourself?

Comment: See, You have declared the queue with size `4` hence It is discarding least recently added element to add the new one Once the queue is full. Just don't write the size in bracket to solve the problem and to print the last `10` elements do it with your own logic or with the logic ,I've posted.

Comment: I still don't understand. int i = list.size(); 
while (i-- > 0 && added < 10) {count += list.get(i) ;} is this right ? And Why the down vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a circular FIFO queue of size 4. 
Imagine it like this.

[image]

So as you start adding elements to the queue. the process will go like this .

1. the first element, 345 goes to the 0th index .
2. the second element,369 goes to the 1st index.
3. the third element ,444 goes to the 2nd index.
4. the fourth element,432 goes to the 4th index.
   At this point, since your queue size is only 4 your queue is full and your write position is just before your HEAD of the queue.
5. when you add 633, it will naturally replace the 0th index(element 345) as that is the next one. that is why now you head of the queue changed to 369 and the last element is now 633.
6. when you add 346 now it will remove 369 and replace it with the new element , but your new head is now 444.

Also reading from the docs.

`CircularFifoQueue is a first-in first-out queue with a fixed size that replaces its oldest element if full.
The removal order of a CircularFifoQueue is based on the insertion order; elements are removed in the same order in which they were added. The iteration order is the same as the removal order.`

if you want to iterate over the 10 recently ordered elements then first increase the size of the queue to more then 10. second iterate the list from the end.

Also you can use stack if the requirement is to get the recently added element(LIFO) which will be more natural.